# Cannot load "fpacutl10.dll" error in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am getting a Cannot Load "fpacutl10.dll" error every time I click on the Style button on the Properties tab in inside of Visual Studios 2010 when I am editing a web page. Has anyone else have this error and how do you fix it?
I have tried reinstalling VS2010 and installing KB2201993 patch from microsoft.

Comment: Well, that's the DLL that is updated by that hotfix.  Not good.  Did you actually get the stack overflow errors?  If not, try uninstalling the hotfix.

Comment: I did have errors where VS2010 would shutdown because of the stack overflow error but the style editor will not come up after the hotfix install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I was able to fix this issue was to re-install the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Append the following to your 'Path' environment variable (without the quotes):
";C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\vwd"

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. I thought I have tried it before.

Comment: There is still one more issue.  Now when you try to use the design wizard, none of the text boxes are available. Can anyone help fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Never personally seen this errror, but  maybe this thread may help: http://forums.asp.net/p/1578911/4125578.aspx

To sum it up, first check to see if the dll is located in Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages

Comment: The dll is located in the Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages directory.

Comment: hmm well another person posted copying fpacutl10.dll, mso.dll and msptls.dll from "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\vwd\" to  "%SystemRoot%\system32" ...I don't know if that'll help.

Comment: I tried moving the three dll's over to the "%SystemRoot%\system32" directory but the style editor is un-usable when you bring up the style editor. The formatting of the controlls in the style editor are messed and do not have any values in some on the controls after moving the dlls.

Comment: :( I didn't mean to make the situation worse :( have you tried doing a repair on VS2010?

Comment: Yes, I have try to repair VS2010 and still have the same issues.

Comment: Does anyone have any other suggestions? I have even tried to install the SP1 for vs2010. I guess the next step is to reformat the computer and start from scratch.