# visual studio 2010 error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I suddenly get this error when I try to switch to the design mode in visual studio 2010.

Cannot load “fpacutl10.dll”

It was working perfect before, Any idea?

Comment: Try this thread first off - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937135/cannot-load-fpacutl10-dll-error-in-vs2010 - fingers crossed...

Comment: Or this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937135/cannot-load-fpacutl10-dll-error-in-vs2010

Comment: I have tried what is said in the thread but it's not working for me.